# Azure Service Bus - Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-rbac

I am trying to access `Azure Service Bus` `Queue` from my `Windows Service` application.
I am following [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/RoleBasedAccessControl/Program.cs) sample.

I want to protect this `Azure Service Bus` using `Azure Service Principal`  Below are the steps I have implemented

1. Register an application named `pc-shutdown-producer` in `Azure Ad`
   representing my `Windows Service`
2. I have created my Azure `service bus namespace` named `shutdowncomputer`
3. Inside `Access control (IAM)`, I have added `Role Assignment` with below values

   - Role - `Azure Service Bus Data Owner`
   - Assign access to - `pc-shutdown-producer`

As per my knowledge above configuration will let `pc-shutdown-producer` application to manage all the resources in the servicebus namespace.
 4. Apart from this, I have also provided `pc-shutdown-producer` delegated API Permissions to access the service bus namespace.

[image]

Below is my C# code.

```
        public async Task Init()
        {
            string authority = $"https://login.windows.net/{TenantId}";

            ITokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateAzureActiveDirectoryTokenProvider(AuthenticationCallback, authority);
            var endpoint = new Uri($"sb://shutdowncomputer.servicebus.windows.net/");
            var entityPath = "shutdownrequest";

            var qc = new QueueClient(endpoint.ToString(), entityPath, tokenProvider);

            Message m = new Message();
            m.Body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{id: 1, name: 'hemant'}");
            m.ContentType = "application/json";
            try
            {
                await qc.SendAsync(m);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //I am getting exception here. 
                //Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation.
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> AuthenticationCallback(string audience, string authority, object state)
        {
            string accessToken = string.Empty;
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AppId)
                .WithAuthority(authority)
                .WithClientSecret(Password)
                .Build();

            var serviceBusAudience = new Uri("https://servicebus.azure.net");

            List<string> claims = new List<string>();
            claims.Add($"{serviceBusAudience}/.default");
            try
            {
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(claims.ToArray()).ExecuteAsync();
                accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //No issue here.
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            //Successfully able to retrieve a token.
            return accessToken ;
        }
```

Upon executing `Init()` , I am getting below exception message.

`Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://shutdowncomputer.servicebus.windows.net/shutdownrequest'. TrackingId:52c0eedcf19d4513a8ec105943859764_G12, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2020-05-11T06:59:01`

**UPDATE 1**

As per @Carl Zhao sugession,  I have provided admin consent to `pc-shutdown-producer` but still having same issue.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insufficient permissions, should add administrator consent:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have provided admin consent but still the same issue.  I am aware of the fact that it can take up to 5 mins to propagate.  I tried this after 20min and still no luck.

Comment: it was my bad.  Instead of adding 'Azure Service Bus Data Owner'  , I added 'Owner' role.  After correcting this in my Azure Service bus namespace I was able to send a message.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to assign the application the **Azure Service Bus Data Owner** role rather than **Owner** (per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724021/azure-service-bus-unauthorized-access-send-claims-are-required-to-perform#comment109183368_61724629)).

[image: A screenshot of the "Add role assignment" page in Azure Portal with two similarly named roles circled: "Owner" and "Azure Service Bus Data Owner."]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **the error was misleading**.

The reason was missing password in configuration files (this happened in Jenkins test agent and it was retrieving the password from some other file where it was not set).

If I had a wrong password, the error is just "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.". But without any password (eg. empty property value), the error was "Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation.".

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve this issue by using connection string without the need of configure roles.
I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=connection-string) when I faced this error.

I copy the most important parts of the link above:

1. On the Service Bus Namespace page, select Shared access policies on the left menu.
2. On the Shared access policies page, select RootManageSharedAccessKey.
3. In the Policy: RootManageSharedAccessKey window, select the copy button next to Primary Connection String, to copy the connection string to your clipboard for later use. Paste this value into Notepad or some other temporary location.

Example c# code for connecting:

```cs
 using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

// the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers
ServiceBusClient client;

// the sender used to publish messages to the queue
ServiceBusSender sender;

// number of messages to be sent to the queue
const int numOfMessages = 3;

// The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
// of the application, which is best practice when messages are being published or read
// regularly.
//
// set the transport type to AmqpWebSockets so that the ServiceBusClient uses the port 443. 
// If you use the default AmqpTcp, you will need to make sure that the ports 5671 and 5672 are open

// TODO: Replace the <NAMESPACE-CONNECTION-STRING> and <QUEUE-NAME> placeholders
var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions()
{ 
    TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
};
client = new ServiceBusClient("<NAMESPACE-CONNECTION-STRING>", clientOptions);
sender = client.CreateSender("<QUEUE-NAME>");

// create a batch 
using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfMessages; i++)
{
    // try adding a message to the batch
    if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage($"Message {i}")))
    {
        // if it is too large for the batch
        throw new Exception($"The message {i} is too large to fit in the batch.");
    }
}

try
{
    // Use the producer client to send the batch of messages to the Service Bus queue
    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfMessages} messages has been published to the queue.");
}
finally
{
    // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
    // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
    await sender.DisposeAsync();
    await client.DisposeAsync();
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the application");
Console.ReadKey();
```